# Why command line doesn't print results of egrep? How to make it print?

Tags: regex, windows, cmd, grep

I'm testing `egrep` in command line but I can't get any results. Here's my input in command line. I want to find some pattern in the file:

```
egrep -i 'this is' C:\regExp\file.txt
```

After I press Enter nothing is printed. Why? How to make it print results?

Comment: "this is" doesn't exist in the file you are passing to `egrep`.

Comment: @SeanBright, no there are some. But it doesn't print anything

Comment: No, there aren't.  `egrep`'s behavior is to print matches in the specified files.  No printing, no matches.

Comment: Yes, it prints results but not from the file I want. I've just created a plain `.txt` file with some matching strings and it has returned results. But it doesn't return anything from other files. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are in Unicode format, your expression will not match, because the characters in the file occupy 2 bytes instead of just one. Such a file would look like this

```
FF FE 66 00 6F 00 6F 00    ÿþf.o.o.
```

rather than this

```
66 6F 6F                   foo
```

in a hex editor.

Open the file in Notepad, then click `File > Save As...` and check the `Encoding` field at the bottom of the dialog. If the file is Unicode encoded, the value `Unicode` will be preselected.